# How to prove $P(A) \cup P(B) \subseteq P(A \cup B) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let C be a non-empty set, that:
$$C\in (\mathcal P(A) \cup \mathcal P(B))\implies C\in \mathcal P(A) \lor C\in \mathcal P(B) \implies C\subseteq A \lor C\subseteq B$$

But my problem is if I can say:

Let $x\in C$, then

$$\begin{align}&  (x\in C \to x\in A) \lor (x\in C \to x\in B) 
\\[1ex] \implies & (x\not \in C \lor x\in A)\lor (x\not \in C \lor x\in B)
\\[1ex] \implies & x\not \in C\lor(x\in A \lor x\in B) 
\\[1ex] \implies & (x\in C \to x\in (A\cup B)) 
\\[1ex] \implies & C\subseteq (A\cup B) 
\\[1ex] \implies & C\in \mathcal P(A\cup B)\end{align}$$

It's right my proof?, I am not sure if I can operate with operators for sets and operators for logic at the same time. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I think a better practice is that you should prove by the definitions of set, with logics, not some other "implies".

Comment: What's $\mathcal{P}(\cdot)$?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(\cdot)$ means the set of all subsets of ..., means the power set

Comment: @manofbear Power set.  "The set of subsets for ..."

Comment: It you are satisfied with my answer, you can accept it by clicking the blank check mark Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to go further. You already established that either $C\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ or $C\in\mathcal{P}(B)$. This implies that either $C\subset A$ or $C\subset B$. Note that both the sets $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $A\cup B$. Thus, in either case, this will lead to $C\subset A\cup B$. Hence, 
$$C\in\mathcal{P}(A\cup B).$$