# Any sets A and B, P(A ∪ B) = P(A) ∪ P(B)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here P is the power set.
Can some show or explain to me how to do this? 
I have failed trying to prove it using laws for set equivalence, it seems my method is wrong.

Comment: Extend to the question, prove the statement above if it's true or disprove using counter example if it's not true

Comment: Hint: try it out on $2$ disjoint non-empty sets.

Comment: HINT: is $A\cup B$ in $P(A)\cup P(B)$?

Comment: What we have is only $P(A)∪P(B)⊂P(A∪B)$ and the proof is given [in here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167938/how-to-prove-pa-cup-pb-subseteq-pa-cup-b/2167969#2167969)

Comment: In addition to other useful comments and an answer, you can also just work with cardinals, if you know that $|P(A)| = 2^{|A|}$.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $A = \{1\}, B = \{2\}$. Does your statement hold?

i.e. Try finding $\mathscr{P}(A\cup B)$ and $\mathscr{P}(A)\cup\mathscr{P}(B)$

Answer (score 3):

$\mathscr{P}(A \cup B) = \mathscr{P}(A) \cup \mathscr{P}(B)$ iff $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$. It's quite trivial to see the right to left implication (we just get the power set of the largest set), if the right hand side fails to hold we have $a \in A, a \notin B$ and $b \in B ,b \notin A$. $\{a,b\}$ is then in neither of $\mathscr{P}(A)$ or $\mathscr{P}(B)$ but *is* in $\mathscr{P}(A \cup B)$, so the left hand side then also fails. This shows the equivalence.